# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can anyone help me resolve this error?

error I'm getting: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')

problem line: `{user.userName.replaceAll(' ', '')}`

i tried changing removing the replaceAll method since it wasn't a huge deal but the same error remained. I also tried writing it like as a regex but no luck:

`{user.userName.replace(/\s+/g, '')}{' '}`

Here's the all the code:

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import Image from 'next/image';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import { GoVerified } from 'react-icons/go';

    import useAuthStore from '../store/authStore';
    import { IUser } from '../types';

const SuggestedAccounts = () => {
  const { fetchAllUsers, allUsers } = useAuthStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllUsers();
  }, [fetchAllUsers]);
  return (
    <div className="xl:border-b-2 border-gray-200 pb-4">
      <p className="text-gray-500 font-semibold m-3 mt-4 hidden: xl:block">
        Suggested Accounts
      </p>
      <div>
        {allUsers.slice(0, 6).map((user: IUser) => (
          <Link href={`/profile/${user._id}`} key={user._id}>
            <div className="flex gap-3 hover:bg-primary p-2 cursor-pointer font-semibold rounded">
              <div className="w-8 h-8">
                <Image
                  src={user.image}
                  width={34}
                  height={34}
                  className="rounded-full"
                  alt="user profile"
                  layout="responsive"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="hidden xl:block">
                <p className="flex gap-1 items-center text-md font-bold text-primary lowercase">
                  {user.userName.replaceAll(' ', '')}
                  <GoVerified className="text-blue-400" />
                </p>
                <p className="capitalize text-gray-400 text-xs">
                  {user.userName}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SuggestedAccounts;
```

Comment: As error message says, you have a `user` with `undefined` `userName`. You cannot do `undefined.replaceAll`

Comment: `user.userName` is undefined. That's what you need to investigate

Comment: change the line to be ```{user.userName?.replaceAll(' ', '')}```. the only issue with this is that when a users username is undefined, it will say ```undefined``` on screen

Comment: One or more of the users in allUsers does not have a userName property.